# Selecting values in attribute table which have alternate same values in two different columns

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, features, select-by-attribute

I am looking for ways to select features in attribute table which have same values but in different column.

In the picture below as you can see `"fid_2"` has values which match `"fid"` but they are different features (shown by black arrow). Here I have manually selected the feature which match but I want to be able to select all three features like the one below automatically. Any ideas?

[image]

When "Select by expression" used
[image]

When I used the Field calculator
[image]

Comment: Given the example it seems that an attribute join fid to fid_2 https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html might be helpful but be VERY careful with FIDs, they're transient. When joined a matched fid to fid_2 will have fully populated rows but an unmatched one will have empty joined columns. If there are more fields or more than one instance of a joined field the process becomes far more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Use the ["Select by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) from the Selection Toolbar

[image: selection]

with the following expression:

```
array_contains(
    string_to_array(
        concatenate_unique("fid_2")
        ),
    "fid")
```

Usually fields like `"id"` and `"fid"` are integers, in this case use a slightly difference expression:

```
array_contains(
    string_to_array(
        concatenate_unique(
            to_string("fid_2")
            )
        ),
    "fid")
```

It uses the following functions: [`array_contains()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#array-contains), [`string_to_array()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#string-to-array), [`concatenate_unique()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#concatenate-unique), and [`to_string()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#to-string).

P.S. I do not really understand whether you need to select `"fid"` in `"fid_2"`, or vise versa.

Comment: It says the expression in invalid. Plus the picture shared is only a part of the selection, I have to do it for a lot of data.

Comment: Please check the updates :)

Comment: I used the second expression which showed false for all. Did not do the selection I wanted. I wanted to select these in a bid to dissolve those features into one and did not want to do it manually. Any further help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That is weird. Can you please share a piece of your data or at least show how the above expression works/fails in your project for your layer?

Comment: I have added the images with the edited question above. The main thing is I want to dissolve the features which have same values but in different column.

Comment: @Taras: proud to have an attribute bamed after you (OP's last screenshot)? ;-)

Comment: @Babel, even though I have this privilege, this does not induce into the working state of the expression. Maybe such guru as you can bring some gorgeous seasoning into the soup :)